# How can I find out why my comment was deleted?

Tags: support, comments, flags

I wrote a comment for a question, which was supposed to help the OP. The comment has been voted 3 or more times, and then deleted.
Why? How can I find that out?

If it was flagged it should have one of the following reasons:

- rude or offensive
- not constructive/off-topic
- obsolete
- too chatty
- other

Comment: What was the content of the comment?

Comment: And what was the question?

Comment: I really can't say without seeing the question, and even then it's hard to tell. Sometimes good comments get removed with lots of bad comments when a moderator does a comment purge to clean up a smelly argument. Sometimes it's just user flags. Sometimes we just hit the wrong button. Don't put too much weight on your comments, they really are just temporary things in most cases.

Comment: It was not intention being rude. But I want to know if somebody is thinking I was rude. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037324

Comment: Your comment was consistent with 'accept rate bullying', which the community frowns upon. I deleted it due to the flags it was collecting. I'm not implying you were _bullying_ anyone, it's just the term used to describe 'prodding' people to accept previous answers.

Comment: @TimPost: Eh, it was borderline.  Oli wasn't being rude, and the OP has ten questions already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to find that out. If you report to which comment you are referring, or to which question you added a comment, a moderator could report the reason it has been deleted.

Comment: how can I "find" a moderator so I can ask him/her ?

Comment: If you ask on the chat for the site where that happened, probably a moderator would tell you.

Comment: I have a similar problem, with respect to a question rather than a comment. The method of posting on the associated chat site is by no means self explanatory. Also, though I went to the chat from the engineering forum, the site moved me to the chat for cross-validated I have no idea why, and saw no way to get back,